# configure: error: Building in the source directory is not supported in this release

Tags: iphone, llvm, toolchain, llvm-gcc

I am trying to build the iPhone toolchain under Ubuntu 10.04 and I encountered an error:

```
mohit@mohit-laptop:~/Documents/toolchain/iphone-dev/llvm-gcc-4.0-iphone$ ./configure     --enable-llvm=`llvm-config --obj-root` --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --target=arm-apple-darwin --enable-sjlj-exceptions --with-heavenly=/usr/share/iphone-filesystem --with-as=/usr/local/bin/arm-apple-darwin-as --with-ld=/usr/local/bin/arm-apple-darwin-ld --enable-wchar_t=no
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... arm-apple-darwin
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
configure: error: Building in the source directory is not supported in this release. See http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html for more details.
```

What does it mean by `Building in the source directory is not supported in this release.`? I svned llvm-gcc-4.0-iphone using:

```
svn checkout http://iphone-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ iphone-dev
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I was trying to build the the directory with all the source files. It had to be built in another folder different than the root directory.